# Query a frame from a video passed as a message by ROS to OpenCV

Tags: ros, opencv, frame, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everybody,
I'm trying to extract a frame from a video passed  by a ROS node to OpenCV. Obviously I made the necessary conversion (via cv_bridge) exactly as suggested in ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages .

```
namespace enc = sensor_msgs::image_encodings;
static const char WINDOW[] = "Image window";
class ImageConverter
{
ros::NodeHandle nh_;
image_transport::ImageTransport it_;
image_transport::Subscriber image_sub_;
image_transport::Publisher image_pub_;

public:
ImageConverter()
: it_(nh_)
{
image_pub_ = it_.advertise("out", 1);
image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("in", 1, &ImageConverter::imageCb, this);

cv::namedWindow(WINDOW);
} 

~ImageConverter()
{
cv::destroyWindow(WINDOW);
}

void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
try
{
  cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::BGR8);
}
catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
{
  ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
  return;
}
 
if (cv_ptr->image.rows > 60 && cv_ptr->image.cols > 60)
  cv::circle(cv_ptr->image, cv::Point(50, 50), 10, CV_RGB(255,0,0));
 
cv::imshow(WINDOW, cv_ptr->image);
cv::waitKey(3);

image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "image_converter");
ImageConverter ic;
ros::spin();
return 0;
}
```

So I don't have to do a cvCapture operation and now the video data (cv_ptr->image) are in the form cv::Mat .
if I write the following code:

```
IplImage* frame_act;
frame_act = cvQueryFrame(cv_ptr->image);
```

i receive this error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘CvCapture*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘IplImage* cvQueryFrame(CvCapture*)’
```

have you same ideas in order to solve this small problem?
thank you very much for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56463/query-a-frame-from-a-video-passed-as-a-message-by-ros-to-opencv/) by [mateo_7_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4299/mateo_7_7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ramanan1991](https://answers.ros.org/users/28120/ramanan1991/) on 2016-10-26**:
I am facing the same problem. Is there a solution? i just need to save the first two frames from a ROS topic, saved into a cv mat variable to perform object tracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your subscriber will receive the video frame-by-frame, so the data referenced by cv_ptr is already a single frame. No need for cvQueryFrame.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mateo_7_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4299/mateo_7_7/) on 2013-02-28**:
oh..ops, ok

**Comment by [mateo_7_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4299/mateo_7_7/) on 2013-02-28**:
thanks!!  but..how can i acquire consecutive frames in separate variables?
ex. first_frame=...
second_frame=....

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-02-28**:
A global std::vector<cv::Mat> would probably work.

**Comment by [mateo_7_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4299/mateo_7_7/) on 2013-02-28**:
thanks again, but please...i'm not so expert about c++. could you explain tour last suggestion?